# Grafana Loki with NFS storageClass encounters 'error creating index client' after a period of time"

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, nfs, grafana-loki, kubernetes-pvc

I have deployed Grafana Loki on my Kubernetes cluster using NFS as the `storageClass`. Initially, everything works fine, and I can collect logs successfully. However, after a while, I start experiencing an "error creating index client" and loki starting dead and crashloopbackoff
which is not encountered when I use CephFS as the `storageClass` instead.

An error log happens when loki run 1 or more hours later(at this time it can collect log ) in loki pod under the statfulset

```
 level=error ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.910299323Z caller=index_set.go:133 table-name=index_19496 msg="failed to open existing index file /data/loki/boltdb-shipper-cache/index_19496/loki-0 
 level=error ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.918924014Z caller=index_set.go:133 table-name=index_19496 msg="failed to open existing index file /data/loki/boltdb-shipper-cache/index_19496/loki-0 
 level=error ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.927720949Z caller=index_set.go:133 table-name=index_19496 msg="failed to open existing index file /data/loki/boltdb-shipper-cache/index_19496/loki-0 
 level=info ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.935410135Z caller=index_set.go:422 table-name=index_19496 file-name=loki-0-1684483385508800075-1684483655.gz msg="downloaded file" total_time=3.96958 
 level=info ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.938327437Z caller=index_set.go:422 table-name=index_19496 file-name=loki-0-1684483385508800075-1684484100.gz msg="downloaded file" total_time=6.71881 
 level=info ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.941700856Z caller=index_set.go:422 table-name=index_19496 file-name=loki-0-1684483385508800075-1684485000.gz msg="downloaded file" total_time=10.0510 
 level=error ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.949063385Z caller=index_set.go:265 table-name=index_19496 msg="sync failed, retrying it" err="recovered from panic opening boltdb file: runtime erro 
 level=info ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.952646375Z caller=index_set.go:422 table-name=index_19496 file-name=loki-0-1684483385508800075-1684485000.gz msg="downloaded file" total_time=3.03557 
 level=info ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.953549481Z caller=index_set.go:422 table-name=index_19496 file-name=loki-0-1684483385508800075-1684483655.gz msg="downloaded file" total_time=3.94770 
 level=info ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.953649583Z caller=index_set.go:422 table-name=index_19496 file-name=loki-0-1684483385508800075-1684484100.gz msg="downloaded file" total_time=4.05850 
 level=error ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.961398153Z caller=index_set.go:265 table-name=index_19496 msg="sync failed, retrying it" err="recovered from panic opening boltdb file: invalid free 
 level=error ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.961514568Z caller=index_set.go:104 table-name=index_19496 msg="failed to initialize table index_19496, cleaning it up" err="recovered from panic ope 
 recovered from panic opening boltdb file: invalid freelist page: 0, page type is unknown<00>  
error creating index client                                                                                                                                                             
 github.com/grafana/loki/pkg/storage.(*store).storeForPeriod                                                                                                                             
     /src/loki/pkg/storage/store.go:245                                                                                                                                                  
 github.com/grafana/loki/pkg/storage.(*store).init                                                                                                                                       
     /src/loki/pkg/storage/store.go:162                                                                                                                                                  
 github.com/grafana/loki/pkg/storage.NewStore                                                                                                                                            
     /src/loki/pkg/storage/store.go:145                                                                                                                                                  
 github.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).initStore                                                                                                                                      
     /src/loki/pkg/loki/modules.go:522                                                                                                                                                   
 github.com/grafana/dskit/modules.(*Manager).initModule                                                                                                                                  
     /src/loki/vendor/github.com/grafana/dskit/modules/modules.go:120                                                                                                                    
 github.com/grafana/dskit/modules.(*Manager).InitModuleServices                                                                                                                          
     /src/loki/vendor/github.com/grafana/dskit/modules/modules.go:92                                                                                                                     
 github.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).Run                                                                                                                                            
     /src/loki/pkg/loki/loki.go:341                                                                                                                                                      
 main.main                                                                                                                                                                               
     /src/loki/cmd/loki/main.go:105                                                                                                                                                      
 runtime.main                                                                                                                                                                            
     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255                                                                                                                                               
 runtime.goexit 
     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581                                                                                                                                          
 error initialising module: store                                                                                                                                                        
 github.com/grafana/dskit/modules.(*Manager).initModule                                                                                                                                  
     /src/loki/vendor/github.com/grafana/dskit/modules/modules.go:122                                                                                                                    
 github.com/grafana/dskit/modules.(*Manager).InitModuleServices                                                                                                                          
     /src/loki/vendor/github.com/grafana/dskit/modules/modules.go:92                                                                                                                     
 github.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).Run                                                                                                                                            
     /src/loki/pkg/loki/loki.go:341                                                                                                                                                      
 main.main                                                                                                                                                                               
     /src/loki/cmd/loki/main.go:105                                                                                                                                                      
 runtime.main                                                                                                                                                                            
     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255                                                                                                                                               
 runtime.goexit                                                                                                                                                                          
     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581                                                                                                                                          
 level=error ts=2023-05-19T08:56:42.962065413Z caller=log.go:103 msg="error running loki" err="recovered from panic opening boltdb file: invalid freelist page: 0, page type is unknown< 
 Stream closed EOF for ecc-devops/loki-0 (loki)
```

My settings:
OS: 3 ubuntu 20.04 k8s node cluster

NFS setting is

```
/mnt/nfs_share  *(rw,async,no_subtree_check,all_squash)
```

and  my stroageClass is "nfs subdir external provisioner" by helm

loki is from  granafa/loki-stack helm chart

Are there any suggestions on how to debug or resolve this issue? I'd appreciate any insights into possible causes and potential solutions.

I've tried like

1. manually create PV instead of storageClass but still error.
2. different NFS setting but still error.
3. restart nfs-server、rpcbind in every k8s node but still not working

in another k8s cluster occur same error like this environment
but when I use cephfs as my PV, loki work just fine
So now I thinking about is loki not support run on NFS.

Comment: Hello,

We experienced the same problem with NFS and the loki stack.

Actually, Grafana recommend againgst running Loki on NFS https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/filesystem/#high-availability

Moving the index to S3 solved our problem.

Comment: Thank you. But NFS is one of most common on-premis storage backend. That is weird loki not support it.